# Linking from jQuery DataTables generated by a JSON file (server-side)

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have a DataTable that works perfectly, as intended, but I did some cheating with the generation of my JSON file. I want some records to link to another page and did so by including the href tag into the JSON. Although this works, I don't really think it's the best way to code this and I assume that this could lead to bigger loading times in the future, when the db will be filled with thousands of records.

DataTable code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function() {
          var oTable = $('#alle_spellen').dataTable( {
            "sAjaxSource": "json.php",
            "aoColumns": [
              { "mData": "kaarting"},
              { "mData": "speler" },
              { "mData": "punten",  "sClass" : "right",
                "sType": "numeric",
                "mRender":  function ( data, type, full ) {
                  if(data > 0) return "<div class='positive'>" + data + "</div>"; 
                  return "<div class='negative'>" + data + "</div>";}
            }],
          })
        } );        
 $(document).ready(function() {});
 </script>
```

JSON file (only 2 records for as an example):

```
 [
     {
         "kaarting": "<a href="datatable_xtabelspel.php?id=id1" Text which includes id1 </a>",
         "speler": "Arne",
         "punten": "17"
     },
     {
         "kaarting": "<a href="datatable_xtabelspel.php?id=id2" Text which includes id2 </a>",
         "speler": "Filip",
         "punten": "-7"
     }
 ]
```

How do I change my script in order to link to the appropriate page (including the db id), and having a JSON like this:

```
 [
     {
         "kaarting": "Text which includes id1",
         "speler": "Arne",
         "punten": "17"
     },
     {
         "kaarting": "Text which includes id2",
         "speler": "Filip",
         "punten": "-7"
     }
 ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does json.php do? Thats the portion that will need to change, or at least whatever query is being executed, the string for kaarting

Comment: My JSON file is generated by a php query. I know how to change my JSON to the JSON I want to use, the problem is that I don't know how to change my DataTables script in order to add a link to the kaarting-string. I suppose I have to use mData for that, but I don't know how to add a link to the specific id.